# two ajax functions at the same time? not working

Tags: php, ajax, mootools

[image]
[image]

I have a simple AJAX script that suppose to to call a PHP file and get data back.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('dbform').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        new Event(e).stop();
        var intervalId =setInterval(function() 
        {
            var Ajax2 = new Request({
                url: '/tools/getdata.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: 'read=true',
                onComplete: function(response)
                {
                    $('results').set('html', response);
                }
            }).send();
        },1000);

        var postString = 'subbutton=' + $('subbutton').value;
        var Ajax = new Request({
            url: '/tools/getdata.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: postString,
            onRequest: function()
            {
                $('message').set('text', 'loading...');
            },
            onComplete: function(response)
            {
                $('message').set('text','completed');
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            },
            onFailure: function() 
            {
                $('message').set('text', 'ajax failed');
            }
        }).send();
    });
});
```

The file that it is submitting too is.

```
$object= new compare();
if(isset($_POST['subbutton'])=='Run')
{
    // This take about 5 minutes to complete
    $run=$object->do_compare();
}

if(isset($_POST['read'])=='true')
{
    /// in the mean time, the first ajax function is suppose to return data from here..while
    // the do_compare() function finish.
    // the problem is that it only return it once the do_compare() finish
    /// 
    echo 'read==true';
}
```

the script is working fine, expect, that when the Ajax request  check the file every one second, it doesn't return  any thing from `$_POST['read']`, till `$run=$object->do_compare();` has finished.

why does it do that? what What I am trying to accomplish is that one Ajax function get data from do_compare function and the other ajax function also independently get that from the getdata.php file.

Comment: `isset()` returns `(bool)true` or `(bool)false` try `if(isset($_POST['read']) && $_POST['read'] == 'true')`

Comment: @Christoph  I just updated an image of the output if you would like to see.

Comment: This javascript confuses me.  It looks like a combination of raw JS, jQuery, and Prototype.  What library are you using?

Comment: What does the console say? do you see the requests there?

Comment: @Sergio  Yes, I do see the request there, please see the pics I included.

Comment: And you did try Christophs answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in line:

```
if(isset($_POST['subbutton'])=='Run')
```

isset returns boolean true or false so if `$_POST['subbutton']` is set than it returns true and due to the weak type system of php `true == 'Run'` because `'Run'` evaluates to true. Use

```
if(isset($_POST['subbutton']) && $_POST['subbutton'] === 'Run')
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['read']) && $_POST['read'] === 'true')
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, however, it didn't solve the problem, it still wait for the first ajax to complete :(

Comment: I would guess that's because http doesn't allow for changing the order of requests. This means it must answer request 1 before request 2. But this only implies per connection. Browsers use 2 connections by default so at least one should finish earlier. I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using session in the PHP AJAX handlers? If so, your session file is probably blocked.

Second: Javascript is internally single threaded in the browser (see google for more information).

Comment: Javascript is indeeded single threaded that's why ajax is in fact asynchronous (by default). That shouldn't be the problem. But session files sounds good. Maybe rolling out a own session system could help.